# Why create=dynamic is deprecated?

Tags: perl, sqlite, dbi, catalyst

I was creating a database model using the command given below.

```
script/myapp2_create.pl model TestDatabase DBIC::Schema \ MyApp2::Schema::TestDatabase create=dynamic \ dbi:SQLite:/tmp/database
```

and I got a warning which says:

```
************************************ WARNING **********************************
* create=dynamic is DEPRECATED, please use create=static instead.             *
*******************************************************************************
```

May I know why create=dynamic is deprecated? I know that

> create=dynamic tells DBIC to read the database every time the
>   application is started to determine the schema (layout of tables,
>   foreign key relations, etc.)

but what's wrong with this? Why create=static is preferred?

Answer (score 2):

From [the Catalyst manual](http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/Catalyst-Manual-5.9003/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Tutorial/03_MoreCatalystBasics.pod):

> Although DBIx::Class has included support for a create=dynamic mode to automatically read the database structure every time the application starts, its use is no longer recommended. While it can make for "flashy" demos, the use of the create=static mode we use below can be implemented just as quickly and provides many advantages (such as the ability to add your own methods to the overall DBIC framework, a technique that we see in Chapter 4).

Answer (score 1):

A guess: perhaps because the dynamic loading functionality moved to [Schema::Loader](http://p3rl.org/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aSchema%3a%3aLoader).